# ImageMagick PDF to JPEG - Auto rotate page from landscape to portrait

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

I have software allowing in input any image with valid **vertical** A4 pages.
My problem is that the PDF we are receiving can possibly have a random page turned into horizontal (landscape) mode.

I don't want to turn the content, only the page to make it feet in the software, like basically a 90 rotate left on all pages that are in landscape orientation.

This is the actual command I use: `convert -scene 1 -density 200 .\TEST2.pdf page-%d.jpg`

**What I have:**

[image: What I get]

**What I would wish:**

[image: What I wish to have]

`-auto-orient` does not solve my problem.

Command:
`convert -auto-orient -scene 1 -density 200 .\multiorientconvert.pdf page-%d.jpg`

Result:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Try `identify TEST2.pdf` to see how the dimensions of each page look. You may have to extract one page at a time, rotate the mis-oriented ones and re-assemble. If so, you can get page 2 with `convert TEST2.pdf[2] ...`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to avoid... Ok, I will pass `pdfinfo` first to try to get wich page are larger than highter and pass a `convert --rotate=90` after extraction on landscape pages.

Comment: @PabloBianchi as I wrote above the `-auto-orient` command doesn't work (I made an edit with a screenshot)